# How to write test case for Threading in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, integration-testing

In my rails application (rails version is 2.3.12), i am using thread for sending mails like below

```
Thread.new{SomeMailer.deliver_method(stuff)}
```

How to test this thread in rails. Actually i wrote this line in model.

Thanks in advance,
Jak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, don't use threads in Rails. Use a single thread per process and use background workers to do stuff like this. Popular workers include [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) and [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

In delayed_job:

```
SomeMailer.delay.deliver_method(stuff)
```

In Resque:

```
class DeliverStuff
  @queue = :mail

  def self.perform(stuff)
    SomeMailer.deliver_method(stuff)
  end
end

# elsewhere
Resque.enqueue(DeliverStuff, stuff)
```